# Infrared beam: AC or DC power supply on the same pins

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, dc

I have an [LA5179](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/images/9819084488734/LA5179-dataSheetMain.pdf) infrared beam from JAYCAR. The [manual](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/images/9819084455966/LA5179-manualMain.pdf) says it has 2 pins which allow for "12 to 250 VAC or DC". The 2 pins allow for the + or - to be on either pin for 12 VDC. The same 2 pins can also be used for 250 VAC.

What kind of circuit is needed to make this possible? Can somebody suggest a circuit I can simulate in LTspice?

Comment: A very wide range power supply in the front end?

Comment: Open it up, look at the relay used internally, figure out the internal DC operating voltage and find a buck regulator circuit that can operate up to a peak input of 375 volts (3% duty cycle on buck regulator to produce 12 volts DC).

Comment: If the circuit only draws a tiny amount of power it's possibly they just rectify it and then use a linear regulator. This would be horrendously inefficient at 250V but if the power usage is tiny, they might not care.